# How to use transactions with SQL Server DDL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transaction, ddl

I have a login table into which all inserts are done by a single stored procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTable(
    LogRefnr int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    LogQuery varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LogTime datetime NOT NULL,
    logQueryDuration int NULL,
    LogSessionID int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Log PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (LogRefnr)
)
go


Create procedure DBO.LogInsert ( @Query varchar(255), @time datetime, @duration int, @SessinID int) as
begin
    Insert into LogTable ( LogRefnr, LogQuery, logQueryDuration, LogSessionID)
    Values  (@Query, @time, @duration, @SessinID);
end;
GO
```

Currently there are about 45500000 rows in that table and I want to direct logging to a different table.

My idea is to use the following script

```
begin Transaction

exec sp_rename LogTable, LogTableOld;

CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTable(
    LogRefnr int IDENTITY(46000000, 1) NOT NULL,            -- greater than select max(LogRefnr) from LogTableOld
    LogQuery varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LogTime datetime NOT NULL,
    logQueryDuration int NULL,
    LogSessionID int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Log2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (LogRefnr);
)
go

sp_recompile LogTable;
go

Commit;
```

Does this work and has minimal impact to other procedures calling LogInsert?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. Transactions apply to DDL and span batches.

I'd do something like this. Note the use of SERIALIZABLE ISOLATION to ensure full isolation and XACT_ABORT which will force a rollback on any error.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
begin Transaction
GO
exec sp_rename LogTable, LogTableOld;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTable(
    LogRefnr int IDENTITY(46000000, 1) NOT NULL,            -- greater than select max(LogRefnr) from LogTableOld
    LogQuery varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LogTime datetime NOT NULL,
    logQueryDuration int NULL,
    LogSessionID int NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Log2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (LogRefnr);
)
go
EXEC sp_recompile LogTable;
go

Commit;
```